# How can I see the explanation of an MSVC /analyze warning from the command line?

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to see the analyzer trace of the MSVC /analyze option:

Consider the following bad code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("Uninit: %d\n", i);
}
```

After running cl.exe with /analyze it shows:

```
>cl.exe /analyze file.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30139 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

file.c
C:\redacted\file.c(6) : warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'i'.: Lines: 5, 6
C:\redacted\file.c(6) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30139.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:file.exe
file.obj
```

So in the lines section it shows line 5 and line 6 only. Obviously it's easy to see the problem in a simple code. But in real code that "Lines" at the end of the warning may show a dozen of lines. Like this:

```
warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'news':  the writable size is '((newslen+wcslen(lastslash)+((sizeof((L"\\?\"))/sizeof(WCHAR)-1))+1))*sizeof(WCHAR)' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written.: Lines: 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 146, 147, 149, 151, 157, 159, 164, 168, 169, 172, 174, 180, 181, 187, 190, 191, 193, 194, 202
```

When using the Visual Studio IDE, it can show detailed explanation for those lines which reveals the assumptions the analyzer had.

But we are not using the IDE because only the Build tools are installed and the compiler is invoked using a build system (Bazel).

Is there a way to show detailed trace of analyzer warnings in the command line?

EDIT: I'm thinking about the messages such as "entering this loop", "assuming x is 0", "taking the then branch", etc. I don't know how these are called, Google failed me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the **Visual C++** `/diagnostic` command-line switch added Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio defaults to `/diagnostic:column` but you may want to use `/diagnostic:caret`.

See this [Visual C++ Team Blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-compiler-diagnostics-improvements-in-vs-15-rc/) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/diagnostics-compiler-diagnostic-options).

Comment: I'm thinking about the analysis trace not the columns, which tells you the messages what the analyzer thinks, such as "Entering this loop", "Assuming x is 0", "Taking then branch", etc. Visual Studio IDE can show these, where does it gets those from?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Can you paste some of the 'additional information' you say you are seeing in the IDE?

Comment: I don't have the IDE installed right now, we are using only the build tools only. I found a [screenshot](https://helloacm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/sample-code.jpg) on web of what I'm thinking of, from this [post](https://helloacm.com/the-c-static-code-analyser-by-visual-studio/).